# Sortable Table Component for React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm looking for a good sortable table to display data--mostly numbers-- in React Native.  I've found react-native-data-table, however I'm a little hesitant to use this library since it's built on listView which is deprecated.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try [react-native-table-component](https://github.com/Gil2015/react-native-table-component). Easy to use and performatic.

Comment: That component does not have sortable function.

Comment: Yeah, I did not find how to sort using function @AnishArya Did you manage to find any good module?

Comment: @Prajna No, I didn't find any. Seems like React Native is not rich in Table components.